# How to hide all li items when clicked on perticular li and again show remaining li item below that items on mouseover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on hide/show `li` using JQuery. My requirement is that when I click on any `li` it should display but hide all other `li` items.When I mouseover on a text '**show all list item but don't hide clicked item**', the remaining list item should come below of that `li` using jquery. I am new to JQuery so don't have that much idea and what is the next process to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.list_style{
list-style-type:none;
}
</style>
<body>

<h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
<ul class="list_style">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
 <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
  <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
<span class="show_all_except_clicked"></span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(".list_style li").on('click',function(){
$('li', $(this).closest('ul')).not(this).hide();
$(".show_all_except_clicked").html("<a href='#' class='show_remaining'>show all list item but don't hide clicked item </a>");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/809224/

Comment: @gitguddoge from list item suppose when i click on item1 hide(item2,item3,item4)  and when mouseove on text it should show item2,item3,item4 now again if i click on item2 hide(item1,item3,item4) on mouseover show all this below that item

Comment: @Anonymous So u means when u clicked on item2 and it have to show item3, item4 when mouseover?

Comment: @gitguddoge yes please tell me the solution for this i am new to jquery so further process i don't know

Comment: try for a 'accordion' but with 'mouseover' feature - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: @Anonymous try out my code and see whether it fulfills your requirements

Comment: @gitguddoge no it is not working  actually i need onmouseover show remaining item and onmouseout hide again.

Comment: @Anonymous i edited the code try again, i missed out some

Comment: @gitguddoge i have checked your updated code still have the same issue.

Comment: @Anonymous could you point out which part does not work? when hide? when hover?

Comment: @gitguddoge from list item  when i click on item1 hide(item2,item3,item4) and when mouseove on text ('show remaining items')it should show item2,item3,item4 ,now again if i click on item2 from that hovered list  hide(item1,item3,item4) and  on mouseover text  show all this below that item

Comment: @edited answer, please try, *put the span tag above the li tag please*

Comment: @gitguddoge sorry bro not it is not working  can you try it in jsfiddle

Comment: @Anonymous copy the whole code of the latest edit, tried in jsfiddle

Comment: @Anonymous is Pasindu's answer is what you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your asked question you only intend to show the items **after the hidden li item** when mouseover(hover) the clicked li item. 
In this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.list_style{
list-style-type:none;
}
</style>
<body>
<span class="show_all_except_clicked"></span>
<h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
<ul class="list_style">
 <li>Menu 1</li>
 <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
  <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $(".list_style li").on('click',function(){
if($(this).hasClass("hide")){
  $(this).removeClass("hide");
  $('li').show();
  $(".show_all_except_clicked").html("");
}else{
    $(this).addClass("hide");
  $('li').not(this).hide();
  $(".show_all_except_clicked").html("<a href='#' class='show_remaining'>show all list item but don't hide clicked item </a>");
 }
});
 $(".show_all_except_clicked").hover(function(){
$("li").not(".hide").show();
},function(){
$("li").not(".hide").hide();
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My idea is to add a class (*assuming there are no other classes*) which is *hide* for the hiding li item and show all the **next** li item in such way

Comment: when i click on list  item3 and mouseover on text it is not showing 1,2,4 list item

Comment: ahh I misunderstood your question, let me fix it

Comment: @Anonymous try again

Comment: it is working  just need your little help from hover list if i click on item again then previous item replaced by this and previous item come inside list

Comment: @Anonymous you can tried this for the latest edits based on what you looking for

Comment: just tell me one thing where have you defined class (.chnaged) class("hide")

Comment: @Anonymous i forgot to remove the function which it is unnecessary tho

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done by adding few css with simple jquery code.**

> Refer below example

```js
/*I have added 2 selectors*/
$(".show-hide, .menu").hover(function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
});
$(".menu li").on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu.active {
  height: auto;
}

.menu li {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li.active {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <span class="show-hide">show / hide</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="active">Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help. Add the mouseover function to the li in the script :

```
$(".list_style li").on('click',function(){
$('li', $(this).closest('ul')).not(this).hide();
$(".show_all_except_clicked").html("<a href='#' class='show_remaining'>show all list item but don't hide clicked item </a>");
});

$(".list_style li").mouseover(function(){
  $('li', $(this).closest('ul')).not(this).show();
});
```

You can check the result in codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMJLye

Comment: but mouseover functions is not working i mean on mouseover hide item again